# Opacity in IE11 with iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, opacity

I have a iframe that is "holding" Facebook Like placed in a div. I need to set this div to become transparent.

I have a css that uses opacity: 0; which works for Firefox and Chrome. However, in IEv11, it is display normally.

I would like to ask if there is anyway to use opacity on IEv11 or make the div transparent in IEv11 as well as the rest of he browser but the "Like" button in the iframe is still clickable.

CSS:
     .hideLike {
        opacity:0.0;
      }

HTML:

```
 <div id="like" class="hideLike">
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?       
          href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FXXXXXX&send=false&layout=button_count&
          width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21"                                                                                                   scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
         style="border:none;left:40px;
         width:450px; height:21px;position:absolute;z-index:1000;"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML and CSS?

Comment: problem solved.
i use filter:alpha(opacity=0); together with opacity:0.0;